# Bind inner class instance to an instance of its outer class

Tags: python, inheritance, inner-classes

### Code first

The goal is to design `OuterBase` such that the following passes:

```py
class Outer(OuterBase):
    def __init__(self, foo: str) -> None:
        self.foo = foo

    class Inner:
        outer: Outer

        def get_foo(self) -> str:
            return self.outer.foo


inner = Outer("bar").Inner()
assert inner.get_foo() == "bar"
```

My question is closely related to this:
[How to access outer class from an inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2024566/19770795)

But it is decisively different in one relevant nuance. That question is about how to access an outer **class** from inside the inner class. This question is about access to a specific **instance** of the outer class.

### Question

Given an `Outer` and an `Inner` class, where the latter is defined in the body of the former, and given an **instance** of `Outer`, can we pass **that instance** to the `Inner` constructor so as to bind the `Inner` instance to that `Outer` instance?

So if we did `outer = Outer()` and then `inner = outer.Inner()`, there would then be a reference to `outer` in an attribute of `inner`.

### Secondary requirements

##### 1) Simplest possible usage (minimal boilerplate)

It would be ideal, if the entire logic facilitating this binding of the instances were "hidden" in the `Outer` class.

Then there would be some `OuterBase` class that a user could inherit from and all he would have to do, is define the `Inner` class (with the agreed upon fixed name) and expect its `outer` attribute (also agreed upon) to hold a reference to an instance of the outer class.

Solutions involving *decoration* of the inner class or explicitly passing it a meta class or defining a special `__init__` method and so on would be considered sub-optimal.

##### 2) Type safety (to the greatest degree possible)

The code (both of the implementation and the usage) should ideally pass `mypy --strict` checks and obfuscate dynamic typing as little as possible.

### Hypothetical real-life use case

Say the inner class is used as a settings container for instances of the outer class, similar to how [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/) is designed. In Pydantic (possibly for various reasons) the inner `Config` class is a class-wide configuration, i.e. it applies to *all* instances of the model (outer class). With a setup like the one I am asking about here the usage of Pydantic models would remain unchanged, but now deviations in configuration would be possible on an *instance* level by binding a specific `Config` instance to a specific model instance.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to define a custom **meta class** for `OuterBase`, which will replace the `Inner` class defined inside the body of any `Outer` with an instance of a special **descriptor**.

That descriptor holds a reference to the actual `Inner` class. It also retains a reference to the `Outer` instance from which its `__get__` method is called and has a generic `__call__` method returning an instance of `Inner`, after assigning the reference to the `Outer` instance to its `outer` attribute.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, ClassVar, Generic, Optional, Protocol, TypeVar


class InnerProtocol(Protocol):
    outer: object


T = TypeVar("T", bound=InnerProtocol)
```

```py
class InnerDescriptor(Generic[T]):
    """Replacement for the actual inner class during outer class creation."""
    InnerCls: type[T]
    outer_instance: Optional[object]

    def __init__(self, inner_class: type[T]) -> None:
        self.InnerCls = inner_class
        self.outer_instance = None

    def __get__(self, instance: object, owner: type) -> InnerDescriptor[T]:
        self.outer_instance = instance
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> T:
        if self.outer_instance is None:
            raise RuntimeError("Inner class not bound to an outer instance")
        inner_instance = self.InnerCls(*args, **kwargs)
        inner_instance.outer = self.outer_instance
        return inner_instance
```

```py
class OuterMeta(type):
    """Replaces an inner class in the outer namespace with a descriptor."""

    INNER_CLS_NAME: ClassVar[str] = "Inner"

    def __new__(
        mcs,
        name: str,
        bases: tuple[type],
        namespace: dict[str, Any],
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> OuterMeta:
        if mcs.INNER_CLS_NAME in namespace:
            namespace[mcs.INNER_CLS_NAME] = InnerDescriptor(
                namespace[mcs.INNER_CLS_NAME]
            )
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)


class OuterBase(metaclass=OuterMeta):
    pass
```

Now this code passes (both runtime and static type checks):

```py
class Outer(OuterBase):
    def __init__(self, foo: str) -> None:
        self.foo = foo

    class Inner:
        outer: Outer

        def get_foo(self) -> str:
            return self.outer.foo


inner = Outer("bar").Inner()
assert inner.get_foo() == "bar"
```

Ignoring type checkers, we could of course also omit the `outer: Outer` annotation.

If we were to instead compromise in the sense that we define some `InnerBase` for `Inner` to inherit from, we could define the `outer` attribute there. That would also eliminate the need for the custom `InnerProtocol` to make type checkers happy. But the trade-off is that users of `OuterBase` would always have to explicitly inherit when defining the inner class as `class Inner(InnerBase): ...`.